# Implementing sql logic for a troublesome requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am working on locations kind of app. So I have a set of records brought down like below:

```
Select Ways.*, ErrorFlag 
from Ways with(no lock) 
inner join Locations with(no lock) 
   on Locations.WayId = Ways.WayId
```

In above set I will get all the ways which have locations.

Now I have a requirement to show a flag with each way such that

condition 1) If any location of the way is not following its rules.

Rule that each location should have start time < end time.

So, now I am just having a algo with me as i am not so good in implementing queries.

For the result set I already have , 
Step 1)I will create a function that will receive a WayId which is already in result set.

Step 2) function will select all the locations from locations table where wayid is = @WayId.

Step 3) Loop through each row id of locations selected  selected in step 2 and will check if start time > end time and if it says yes, It will return true other wise it will keep going ahead and after passing through each row, It will return false.

How should I implement that. Could you suggest something? Or if you have any better approach. Please do share a query example so that It will become a bit easy for me to understand..

Table structure is below:

Ways

```
WayId    colorcode     weight      length
1         red            50         500m
2         blue           100        200m
```

Locations

```
LocationId WayId   Starttime    Endtime
1           1        12:00AM     11:00AM      
2           1        1:00 PM     2:00 PM
3           1        3:00 PM     4:00PM
```

Output: The below output is needed as Way with WayId=1 have locations so it will display but way with id=2 is not having any locations so it will not show.

2) The way has three locations so it will count and show

3) The way should show ErrorFlag=true as one of it's locations have start time greater than end time.

```
WayId   colorCode  weight length ErrorFlag  Locations
1        red        50     500    true         3
```

Comment: How do you decide that 12:00am is greater than 11:00am?

Comment: What is the SQL type of the `Starttime` and `Endtime` columns in your `Locations` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about your source data types:

```
DECLARE @Ways TABLE (
    WayId INT,
    ColorCode VARCHAR(10),
    [Weight] INT,
    [Length] INT
)

DECLARE @Locations TABLE (
    LocationId INT,
    WayId INT,
    StartTime TIME(0),
    EndTime TIME(0)
)

INSERT INTO @Ways
SELECT 1, 'red', 50, 500
UNION
SELECT 2, 'blue', 100, 200

INSERT INTO @Locations
SELECT 1, 1, '12:00', '11:00'
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, '13:00', '14:00'
UNION
SELECT 3, 1, '15:00', '16:00'
```

But you could do this:

```
SELECT  w.WayId, 
        w.ColorCode, 
        w.[Weight], 
        w.[Length], 
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (  
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM @Locations lerror 
                            WHERE lerror.WayId = l.WayId 
                            AND lerror.StartTime > lerror.EndTime
                         )
             THEN 'true'
             ELSE 'false'
        END AS ErrorFlag, 
        COUNT(l.WayId) AS Locations
FROM @Ways w
JOIN @Locations l ON w.WayId = l.WayId
GROUP BY w.WayId, w.ColorCode, w.[Weight], w.[Length], l.WayId
```

If your types for the `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns in the `Locations` table are different, you just need to establish how you determine whether one value is greater than the other and replace my `lerror.StartTime > lerror.EndTime` logic with your own.

Comment: As I have studied that sub-query executes first and then only the main query. So how is it possible for the above sub-query to select the records based on  L.WayId as "L" is the part of main query and not the part of subquery?

Comment: What makes you think the subquery within the `SELECT` clause executes first? The `FROM` clause is executed first, with the `SELECT` clause (including any subqueries) coming much later in the execution order (in fact, only `DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY` and `TOP` are processed after `SELECT`). Therefore, it is perfectly possible to reference a table from the `FROM` clause in a subquery within the `SELECT` clause. If you wanted to, you could also achieve this by joining to the table, but I felt the above implementation was clearer as to its intent.